# statistical match or coincidence

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have the following question and problem. We have found in a site two deposits with the same amount of ancient greek coins, 54 in each deposit, so they have the same value.

Is there a statistical way or technique to show that this is not a mere coincidence? That is, that behind this fact underlays a reason to deposit the same amount of money in each group of coins. I mean that, mathematically, it is very difficult for this coincidence to occur
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What hypotheses do you intend to test, using what information?  If it's based only on coin counts, the two sites are identical and no (reasonable) statistical test will conclude otherwise.

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to prove, that both deposits are identical and therefore have the same meaning. But I would like to prove it using test hypotheses, in order to make clear that statistically there is not differences between the two deposits

Comment: What you ask for makes little sense from a statistical perspective.  The way you prove that two numbers are equal is to show they are the same.  In this case, 54=54.  Even when both numbers are uncertain--for instance, maybe you haven't found all coins in one (or both) deposit--there is no evidence in these data that the actual numbers are different.  Statistics cannot magically add anything to this basic analysis.

Comment: I agree with you, the best prove is the number of coins in each deposit, which is the same. However, I thought that test hypothesis with a p-value over 0.5 is indicative of no differences between the two population (coins) , which I could use to interpret the deposits of coins as part of an administrative payment, but I might be wrong

Comment: With your edits I see now what your question is.  I wonder whether you or others have found deposits you could compare to this one.  In particular, how many coins appear in these others?  That would be valuable information, for otherwise any conclusions you draw from this coincidence would rely on (a great deal of) speculation.

Comment: there have been found two different deposits and both contain the same amount of coins. On my humble opinion, this is not a mere coincidence but rather it is due to the fact that both deposits of coins were supposed to be used for the same purpose. I just wonder if there is any way to suggest that statistically it is very difficult that it is a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Veru much appreciated.